# calling Azure API with InvokeApiAsync function (Woking Fine).I want to read those values

Tags: c#, .net, json, console-application, azure-mobile-services

Code
(front end)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var client = new MobileServiceClient("MYURL", "MYKEY");
        var arguments = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "UserName", "snegi" }, {"Password", "test123" }
        };
```

**Calling API**

```
var result = client.InvokeApiAsync<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<AuthenticationResponse>>("authenticateuser", HttpMethod.Get, arguments);
```

**here i want to read a value returned by API**

```
        Console.WriteLine(result.UserId);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }


    public class AuthenticationData
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }


}
public class AuthenticationResponse
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

}

**JSON RESULT**

```
{ { UserID: 3022 }
```

Comment: Do you have problem with your code? Errors?

Comment: var result = client.InvokeApiAsync<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<AuthenticationResponse>>("authenticateuser", HttpMethod.Get, arguments); // In variable result i'm not getting values returned by API authenticate result

Comment: it's also show the exception is ..
{"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type

Comment: I think exception is pretty self-explanatory... If you still not solved the problem please make sure to edit your post with details you've hinted in comments including actual JSON response (i.e. captured with Fiddler).

Answer (score 2):

When I do something like this, I prefer indicating the return type I am waiting from the remote method. Here, you can either expect to get integer with the user ID from the remove method, or you can also expect a "user" object (I am assuming you must be using Entities) containing its ID and some other data.

You can try something like this:

```
int result = await client.InvokeApiAsync<string>("authenticateuser", HttpMethod.Get, arguments);
```

Or

```
User result = await client.InvokeApiAsync<User>("authenticateuser", HttpMethod.Get, arguments);
```

Of course, assuming you have an API called "authenticateuser" and that the remote method (after checking login/mdp credentials) returns either the associated user ID or related user entity object.

The serialization/ deserialization of the User object is done automatically, without you worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys , i just solved this problem from this method..

```
 var result = client.InvokeApiAsync<IEnumerable<AuthenticationData>>("authenticateuser", HttpMethod.Post, arguments);
```